# How to enabled verbose logs in VSTS Release definition task?

Tags: logging, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I need logs more detailed when I run a Release Definition on VSTS. How enabled verbose logs on all Release Definition or on a task of the Release Defintion ?

Comment: Do you solve this issue by setting system.debug variable to true? (If isn't existing, add it to release definition)

Comment: There's a very useful Microsoft page that has many suggestions for adding tracing and troubleshooting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Set the `system.debug` variable to `true` in the Variables tab of the release definition; that will get you more verbose logs. Whether those logs will contain any information that's useful to you or not is another story.

Comment: This is really useful. Just add a variable called "System.debug" and set its value to "true". Helped me debug problem with calling (not a problem of the script) https://github.com/wulfland/vso-agent-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/WindowsMachineFileCopy/WindowsMachineFileCopy.ps1